# Am I a low tenor or a high baritone?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, tenor

I'm a 13 year old singer, my voice already dropped (I think), i don't think it is likely that it'll change a whole lot more.

But anyways, my vocal range is : E2-B5 (a lot of low tenors have this range more or less, like Miljenko Mattijevik from Steelheart, quite a few of them can go even lower, like Rob Halford from Judas Priest)

Registers:

E2-F2: Breathy Low Chest voice

F2-G#4: Low-to-Upper Chest voice

G#4-C5 or C#5, maybe higher I havent really tested: Mixed voice

D5-B5: Lower-Upper Head voice

C6-C#6: Very High Head voice, it doesn't hurt or anything but it's too thin 
so I don't make a lot of use of it (yet)

- In vocal fry I can do a Bb1 but I can't make a use of it because its too quiet
- My falsetto range is quite small and useless, i think its underdeveloped (about G4-E5, and they go breathier as i go higher), my high notes I prefer to hit them in Head voice

I can't really tell where my "breaks" are, especially because now i'm doing things like stretching chest voice a little bit more, I never really experienced any Chest-Head breaks, or Chest-Mid breaks or cracks, maybe I learned how smoothly connect these registers over time, I used to sing a lot in Head voice with a lot of pharyngeal resonance trying to sing along to Axl Rose from Guns N'Roses, it didn't hurt, but, didnt sound good  .

I don't know where my tessitura is, really, But I can say i'm more comfortable on notes kinda below B4 or C5.

Approximatively I might say my tessitura is around: F3-A4, but i'm TOTALLY not sure.

Also, my speaking voice is relatively low, I don't do it on purpose or anything like that, but my speaking voice is usually between A2-D3, which is, I think, kinda really too low for a tenor.

I have never had any true private singing lessons, I did try some voice programs though, (Per Bristow, Singing Success, but then I thought SLS just wasn't my thing, and I went for Ken Tamplin Vocal Academy's course How to sing better than anyone else, which suits me much better, because  I'm a hard rock singer)

I started singing seriously about 6 months ago, my range, abilities, power, tone and pitch have improved A LOT since then. My ranged used to be something like G2-E5.

Anyways, do you guys have any ideas what I might be ?

Comment: Related: [Is there a standard range for a baritone? What is it?](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/7992/28) and [Accepted ranges for SATB choral works?](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/5977/28)

Comment: I'll reiterate the point that's in MattPutnam's answer: you're 13, so at this point, who knows what you are? You may have gone through the most prominent vocal change, but at 13, your voice hasn't settled in. This doesn't mean that your range will lower - it very well might get higher again. I was a bass at 17 and I'm now a high tenor at 26.

Comment: I think you are a low tenor. Probably a dramatic tenor or a heldentenor?

Answer (score 8):

Men's voices continue to change well into their twenties.  I started off as a bass (solid E2) and ended up as a mid-high bari.  There's not much point in worrying about vocal classification right now.

Anyway, something's off with your octave numbers, or your labeling of vocal registers.  C6 is soprano high C.  There's no way you're singing that in modal voice.

Take some real, in-person lessons.  Those voice programs are dangerous, especially at your age.

Comment: I second @MattPutnam! You are too young to even worry about these things. Your voice is a physiological thing and it is still growing and changing throughout your teen years. You are really too young to take lessons from a voice teacher. But by all means stay away from video courses and the like. You could hurt your voice. Just relax, and sing, and don't push it and don't worry. It will take several years for things to settle out and for your voice to mature. This is perfectly normal for a young man.

Comment: @WheatWilliams Great advice in general.  The problem is that this young man is a hard rock singer!

Comment: Your first sentence is far too limiting. Try ... "Human voices continue to change through the person's lifetime." At 16-18, I was a solid bass: low end of my range was two octaves below middle C. By late 20's I still had a bass range, but my top end had moved up markedly so I generally sang as a baritone. Now at 61, the bottom end of my bass range has gone (I can only manage second F below middle C), but my high range has gone up to the second D above middle C in chest/mixed voice. However, my falsetto has completely cut off only a note or two above that. Yes, take some lessons!!

Answer (score 0):

I think based on the fact that your mixed voice going up to D flat (Db5) above the tenor high C I think you are a Heldentenor with a bass range down to low E and a soprano quasi-falsetto up to soprano high B. Have you ever tried singing an operatic tenor high C?