# My voice chest range is D#2-G#4.What is my voice type?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training, bass-voice

I extended a little my voice chest range recently.It was G2-D4,now it's D#2-G#4.1) How to determine the type of voice by range? Chest or chest+head or chest + head + falsetto? 2) What is my voice type?
I used a site "singingcarrots" and app "Sing Sharp" to determine my vocal chest range.
I attached a link to cover on youtube.Maybe it helps.
P.S. It was recorded a long time ago and I don't hit notes right.
[Cover on Johnny Cash Hurt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxNegtSdU74&ab_channel=AlexReyder)

Comment: Why are folk so keen to pigeon-hole their voices???

Comment: I just wanna know who I am

Comment: @Tim (I guess the easy answer is so they can integrate with pigeon-holed systems. You walk into a choir and they say "Basses over here, tenors over there," where do you stand? You order some sheet music that comes in either tenor or bass, which do you order? Of course, Alex, the answer sometimes comes down to the particular piece and *its* range. Plus, it has to do not just with what you can hit, but how much comfort and "vocal weight" you have on that note.

Comment: @AlexReyder You're a singer whose range currently extends from D#2 to G#4. That's who you are.

Comment: Cheekiness aside, your range as you describe it places you securely as a bass. See [Accepted ranges for SATB choral works?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/5979/70803).

Comment: @Aaron indeed, I get the impression that even the rigid operatic _Fach_ system is somewhat relaxed compared to earlier decades.  Alex: Sing what you sing well!  Identifying your voice type can help you identify repertoire that you sing well, but "I ought to be able to sing this because I am X" isn't very helpful with songs that you don't sing well.

Comment: You may have a label 'tenor' or 'bass', but it's more dependent on the quality of your voice in those ranges, particularly at their extremities. And what you're going to be expected/ing to sing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your chest range you’d be seen as bass or bass-baritone. But these classifications can not alone be made by range, but also need to take into account the quality of the voice within this range, what feels good to you and such stuff. Also if your voice still has potential in development whether that potential is rather up or down. A range of D#2-G#4 would encompass a middle bass register (about Eb2 - C4), a low baritone register (about F2 - F4), a high baritone register (about A2 - G4) or even a low tenor register (about C3 - A4). So try to evaluate in which of these regions you feel most at home in. Things being said, if your voice goes to a low Eb you’re probably not a tenor, but a baritone or a versatile bass.

And yes, of course Falsetto voice range matters *if you have a trained falsetto voice*. If you are contratenor this matters.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to determine the type of voice by range? Chest or chest+head or chest + head + falsetto?

Your chest voice is used to determine your vocal range. Falsetto is generally considered "extra", and head voice is somewhat ambiguous, but is generally considered either a version of falsetto, a "pre-falsetto" range, or a timbre, but nevertheless an extension of one's basic range. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_voice))

> Falsetto is not generally counted by classical purists as a part of the vocal range of anyone except countertenors. There are exceptions, however, such as the baryton-Martin which uses falsetto. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsetto))

#### What is my voice type?

Please see [Accepted ranges for SATB choral works?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/5977/70803)